# Selenium automate firebase google sign in process

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firebase-authentication

I am trying to login firebase google sign in using selenium web driver. But I am getting the following error when enter email and click next button:

```
**Couldn't sign you in**
This browser or app may not be secure.
Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can refresh your screen and try again to sign in.

// Redirected to reject url
https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/deniedsigninrejected?
```

I used chrome browser and chrome driver version 79.0.3945.79.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you add the code you are using to find the Next button and click it?

Comment: Here is the code that i am using to find the Next button and click it.             
 await.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='identifierId']")).sendKeys("amstriker.dev@gmail.com");
              await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='identifierNext']")).click();

Comment: Comment out the click next part and click next manually after your script stops. Does that also fail?

Comment: Yes, It is the same problem when test on selenium web driver.  But one thing i copied the link , paste the real browser and test it .After that It works manually test on real browser.

Comment: Ok now we are getting somewhere. What driver version are you using and what browser?

This is something you should put in the ticket at the top.

Comment: I used chrome browser and chrome driver version 79.0.3945.79.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you provide email to sign in which didn't access this firebase.

May be not the best solution.But it works best for me. 
Provide email to sign in should be the owner email, which is used to specify who can full acess firebase. So, it works property when you use owner email.